# How do I connect to Microsoft Teams via PowerShell through a proxy?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have issues running the `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $UserCredential` command.  I get the following error:

`AADSTS50158: External security challenge not satisfied`

My PowerShell Profile looks like:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy "http://myproxy.mydomain.com:9999"
$Wcl=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Creds=Get-Credential
$Wcl.Proxy.Credentials=$Creds

[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy = new-object system.net.webproxy('http://myproxy.mydomain.com:9999')
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.credentials = $Creds
```

I can see the `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` come through in Fiddler. Oddly, the host in Fiddler is actually the actual `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` command. The error in Fiddler is
`HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required` and I can see the following Cookie
`Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="My super secret Realm"`

[image: Fiddler]

I can get to all other Office 365 workloads that I have tried.  How do I get `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` to use my proxy credentials?